# Contentful line break in single line field

Tags: php, contentful

is it possible to force `<br>` on a `single line` element of Contentful?

Writing `<br>` or `\n` just add those character in the string.

Is there a way to parse those elements?

Answer (score 2):

Markdown accepts certain HTML elements and `<br>` is one of them. If you are rendering your content on your web project with a Markdown [parser](https://github.com/markedjs/marked), you can pass in the single-line field (with the `<br>` tag) and it will render as expected so long as that property is being parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer mate.. And what about if I've not MD parser?

Comment: @Christine_W I use the technique you describe. I use plain HTML tags in my markdown, and if needs be I can change or modify them in my parser. The parser I'm using (marked.js) will render them if I set sanitize to false